# How do I insert and update a JSON using Java SDK v2

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Apologies if this question has been asked before, but I couldn't get an answer even after a few hours of browsing.

My requirement is simple: I want to Insert and Update an entire JSON into DynamoDB table using SDK v2.
Instead of using Map<String, AttributeValue>, I want to use a HashMap<String, Object> and update the entire JSON. I assumed this would be a standard use-case given that DynamoDB is to used with structured data.

Please help!